# How to change 000-000 to 000000 in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10

I'm making an odoo10 module, but I need to change a string like

> 000-000

to

> 000000

How can I do that?

Comment: Simply: `x= x.replace("-", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("000-000".replace("-", "")) #Output: "000000"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Oldstr = “000-000”
Newstr = Oldstr.replace(“-”,””)
```

That should do it.
What I did:

1. Make the string “000-000”
2. Made a new string and replaced the “- ”in the old one  with nothing and saved it in a new variable

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but are those oblique double-quotes OK as string delimiters?